# How do I loop through array elements infinitely, whilst making the current array element visible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, for-loop

I wish to create a text animation where words are being displayed, one after another and with moderate speed. First I tried achieving this with an onClick event.

```
const arrayOfWords = ["Acerbity", "Anomalous", "Asymetrical", "Analytical", "Arbritrary"];
const targetOfDisplay = document.querySelector("h1#heading");
const clickElement = document.querySelector("button");
targetOfDisplay.innerHTML = arrayOfWords[0]; 
let i = 0;

function changeWord(){
    if(i < arrayOfWords.length-1) {
      i++;
    }
    else{
      i=0;
    }
  return targetOfDisplay.innerText = arrayOfWords[i];
}
clickElement.onclick = changeWord;
```

Then I thought about making animation out of it.

I tried working with a timer, but I just can't figure it out.

```
const arrayOfWords = ["Acerbity", "Anomalous", "Asymetrical", "Analytical", "Arbritrary"];
const targetDisplay = document.querySelector("h1#heading");
let i = 0;
targetDisplay.innerHTML = arrayOfWords[0]; 

function animateWords(){
    if(i < arrayOfWords.length-1) {
      i++;
    }
    else{
      i=0;
    }
  return targetDisplay.innerText = arrayOfWords[i];
}

const currentWord = 0;
const timer = setInterval(onTick,50);

function onTick(){
  const change = targetOfDisplay.innerText[currentWord];
  currentWord++
  if(current === arrayOfWords.length){
    complete();
    return;
  } 
}
function complete(){
  clearInterval(timer);
  timer = null;
```

Comment: You never call `animateWords()`. Maybe you want `const timer = setInterval(animateWords, 50);`.

Comment: You may want to look at [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) and [Using CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions).